# Extension of String - Error received 'No Member'

Tags: ios, string, swift, xcode7, swift2

I have created an extension of String:

```
extension String {
    var cSym:String? {
        return CurrencyConversion.getCurrencySymbolWithCode(self)
    }
}
```

When I go to use the extension I can see it and Xcode points to the extension fine, but then when I go to run I get and error stating:

> Value of 'String' has no member 'cSym'

```
class func getCurrency(code : String) -> String {
    return code.cSym ?? "$"
}
```

I have been looking at the Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html and I can't see what the problem is. I have copied and pasted the code snippet from the documentation as well and I get the exact same error for the Double.

Maybe it's a Swift2.1 issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue, Xcode seemed to have removed the targeting link to the one I was currently running from.

Not an ideal situation but if anyone comes across this, just double check Xcode hasn't removed the linkage for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your extension from a framework or in anything that's not in the same scope as the extension itself, you should mark its content with `public` to make it available (Swift methods are `internal` by default):

```
extension String {
    public var cSym:String? {
        return CurrencyConversion.getCurrencySymbolWithCode(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but this is still causing the same error.

Comment: You're welcome. Was I wrong in my diagnostic, no scope problem? In this case I hope you find an explanation and a solution. :)

Comment: Turns out Xcode decided to remove the link to the Target I was working on. Typical!

Comment: Ah! Yeah I should have told you about this possible situation too, I didn't think about it when making my answer. I'm glad you found out what was wrong.

Comment: Yeah it drove me a bit crazy, I don't know how it lost the link to the target. I keep finding strange bugs in the new Xcode. Seems to get worse than better.